# Cannot change the password via admin panel

Tags: magento2, admin-panel, magento2.2.6, change-password

We have set the **password change** as **recommended**. However, when we tried to change the password via the `change your password` link in the admin panel, it doesn't lead to anywhere.

[image]

Also, I'm not receiving any emails when trying to reset the password via admin login. However, I'm getting the below alert message when trying to reset the password:

[image]

Could anyone please help me with this?

**Update:**

Tried to update the password in the **system** -> **permissions** -> **All users** and clicking the current user and trying to apply a new password. When saving with the new password it gives this error:

> 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender

But the password change seems to go through even though I get this error message.

What's this error message and is this related to not receiving emails when trying to reset the password in the login panel.

Comment: When you click on change your password then what happens?

Comment: @SukumarGorai When I click the "change your password" link, it just loading the page and nothing happens

Comment: If that not works then try the answer which is magento's default option to update passwords anytime.

Answer (score 1):

If your link isn't working then there is an alternative option.

**Alternative option to change password:**

**1.** Login to admin and click on Account Settings as show below:
[image]

**2.** Then you will be redirected to change password screen as show below:
[image]

**3.** Now you can change your admin password with new one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I will try it but do you have any idea why the password change link doesn't work? What could be the issue?

Comment: You need to check logs and also console log if there is any errors. Because without checking the issue in the system it's not possible to identify the issue.

Comment: I have checked the log files and the console log but there were no errors.